# Tabbed pane does not appear when running Java swing app. nested classes approach

Tags: java, swing, inner-classes, jtabbedpane

I am using nested private classes to build a Java Swing application.
The tabbedPane does not appear when running the application.
When run, the application shows a blank frame. The app exits on close.

The main question is, what are the options to get the tabbedPane to appear? A second question is if nested classes are a good approach/ am I using them correctly?

The following are the relevant classes.

**Constructor**

```
package personalApp;

//imports

public class SwingApp {
//Attributes
//----- CONSTRUCTOR ------
SwingApp() throws IOException{
f1 = new Jframe();
 JTabbedPane z = new tabbedPane();
        f1.add(z);
        f1.setVisible(true);
        f1.setSize(400,400);
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

**tabbedPane**

```
   private class tabbedPane extends JTabbedPane {
        @Override
        public void setVisible(boolean aFlag) {
            super.setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public Component add(String title, Component component) {
            super.add("Contacts", new panel2());
            return new panel2();
        }

    }
```

**panel2**

```
private class panel2 extends JPanel{

        @Override
        public void setLayout(LayoutManager mgr) {super.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());}

        @Override
        public void setBackground(Color bg) {super.setBackground(mainColor);}

        @Override
        public void setVisible(boolean aFlag) {super.setVisible(true);}

 public void add(Component comp, Object constraints) {
  //There is a JTable, JScrollPane(JTable),JToolbar and JButton added within this method. They all follow the same structure.
            openButtonPhonebook = new JButton("Open");
         //multiple lines of GridBagConstriants. c = GridBagconstraints.
            super.add(openButtonNotebook,c);
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {new SwingApp();}
```

I have tried adding the components in multiple add methods. This gives an error for overwriting the same method.

I have tried and was successful with adding components within the constructor method. This is causing the code to become hard to navigate. I want to use more abstraction to improve the readability of the code.

Ultimately, I am building a swing app with too much code to put in a constructor method. If there are alternatives to nested classes which improve readability, I am open to them.

Comment: Why are you creating two instances of `panel2` in `add`?  Which raises the question of, why are you overriding `add` and circumventing the normal workflow?

Comment: I might consider doing things like using a "model" and "factory" workflow to make it more "abstract" and I most certainly wouldn't be overriding methods like `add`, `setLayout`, `setVisible` or `setBackground`

Comment: Also add in the fact that `add` is never called

Comment: As a more "general" recommendation, I would consider doing some research on "composition vs inheritance" and "model-view-controller"